# Unit of work across multiple actors Akka.Net

Tags: akka.net

I got a requirement that two actors are need to be in the same unit of work, my understanding is actor is location transpancy which mean that it can be in any where, anyone got any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate Actor coordinate the unit of work for the two Actors involved. This could be basic actor supervision whereby the supervisor is responsible for the workflow / unit of work, but delegates the actual business processes to the two Actors you mention.

Comment: For my case, ActorB will do the eventstore persistent and ActorC will do the readmodel generation, let say i add another supervisor ActorA to monitor B and C, do you mean that let B and C do stuff with their own transaction, and if A detect that any one of them failed, manually delete the other one's record?